# Can I access Gears from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-gears

Developing extensions for Google Chrome 4.x. I'd like to keep a couple of parameters persistent, and thought about using Google Gears' Database object - since it's always installed with Chrome.
But I couldn't find any documentation that will tell me if it's possible. The only relevant sentence [I could find](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/gears/api_database.html) was

> Data is stored using the same-origin
> security policy, meaning that a web
> application cannot access data outside
> of its domain

Is that evenrelevant to an extension, that runs locally? Is there anything else that may prevent me from using the Database object?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know, but if you can't, do file a bug for it :)

Comment: Ok, I tried a straight-forward approach (inserting row, reading it back and displaying it) - works in an HTML, doesn't work in the extension. Where should I report a bug? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this thread about people using different features of gears in their chrome plugins:
http://groups.google.com/group/gears-users/browse_thread/thread/396c542a7f6d44ce?pli=1
yes.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a deeper look.